Does $\frac{1}{(1+x)\cdots(1+x^n)}$ converges uniformly for $x\geq 0$?
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$

Does $\displaystyle
\frac{1}{\left(1 + x\right)\cdots\left(1 + x^{n}\right)}$ converges
uniformly for $x\geq 0$ ?.

$$
\mbox{Let}\ \on{f}_{n}\left(x\right) =
\frac{1}{\left(1 + x\right)\cdots\left(1 + x^{n}\right)},\quad \mbox{then}\quad\on{f}_{n}\left(x\right)\geq \on{f}_{n + 1}\left(x\right)\geq 0
$$
$$
\mbox{The limit}\ \on{f}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\on{f}_{n}\left(x\right)\ \mbox{exists.}\
\on{f}_{n + 1}\left(x\right) = \frac{\on{f}_{n}\left(x\right)}{1 + x^{n}}
$$

It seems not easy to find $\on{f}\left(x\right)$ for
$x \in \left(0,1\right)$ ?.
How to discuss the uniform convergence ?.

It is $0$ K if we just consider it on $\left[1,\infty\right)\ldots$ but for $0 < x < 1$ ?.

Let $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x).$ Since $f(x)\le f_n(x)$ we get $$0\le \limsup_{x\to 1^-}f(x)\le \limsup_{x\to 1^-}f_n(x)=f_n(1)$$ As the inequality holds for any $n$ we get
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}f(x)=0.$ The sequence $f_n(x)$ is convergent uniformly on $[0,x_0]$ for any $x_0<1$ as
$$-\log f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log(1+x^k) $$ and $0\le \log(1+x^k)\le \log(1+x_0^k)\le x_0^k.$ Thus by the Weierstrass majorization test the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(1+x^k)$ is uniformly convergent for $0\le x\le x_0$ to a positive function $g(x).$ Hence the function $g(x)$ is positive and continuous. As $f(x)=e^{-g(x)}$ the function $f$ is continuous as well. Summarizing the function $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)\searrow f(x).$ By the Dini theorem the convergence is uniform.

Should $-\log(1+f(x))$ be $-\log f(x)$? And it should point out that $f(x)>0$ when $x\in[0,x_0]$.

Thanks, a misprint

Actually, the limit function $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$  and $0\leq f(x)\leq1$. So the left limit $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$  exists and $$0\le \lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)\leq\lim_{x\to 1^-}f_n(x)=f_n(1)=\frac{1}{2^n},\forall n\in\mathbb N.$$

@Riemann You are right, but I prefer to leave the way it is, just to emphasize that  the monotonicity of $f_n$ and hence $f$ close to $1$ is not essential.

You can use Dini's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem. To apply this theorem, it remains to prove that the limit function is continuous.
1.First, we prove it is continuous in $x=1$. We have $f(1)=0$. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Let $n$ such that $\frac 1 {1.9^n} <\varepsilon$. There exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all $1 -\delta < x < 1$, $x^k$ remains superior to $0.9$ for all $k$ between $0$ and $n$. Therefore, $\frac 1 {1+x^k}\le \frac 1 {1 + 0.9}$ for all $0 \le k \le n$ and $f(x) \le f_n(x) \le \frac 1 {1.9^n} <\varepsilon$. This proves the continuity of $f$ in $1$.

Now we see the continuity on $[0,1)$. For this, we actually prove that $f$ is locally lipschitz. Let $0 \le x < y <1$. Using the following inequality (which can be proved by induction, see for example How to prove the following inequality $|\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}a_i-\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}b_i| < n\delta$?)

$$ \left| \prod_{k=1}^n a_k - \prod_{k=1}^n b_k \right| \le \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k - b_k|,$$
we get
$$ |f_n(y) -f_n(x)|  \le \sum_{k=1}^n \left|\frac 1 {1+y^k} - \frac 1 {1+x^k} \right| \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y^k-x^k} {(1+y^k)(1+x^k)} .$$
Using $\frac 1 {1 + x^k} \le 1$ and a similar inequality for $y$ we get (remember $y > x$!)
$$ |f_n(y) -f_n(x)|  \le \sum_{k=1}^n  y^k-x^k \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty  y^k-x^k = \frac 1 {1-y} - \frac 1 {1-x} = \frac {y-x}{(1-x)(1-y)}. $$
For $x,y \in [0, 1-\delta]$, the $\frac {1}{(1-x)(1-y)}$ is bounded by $1/\delta^2$. Passing to the limit, this proves $f$ is $1/\delta^2$-Lipschitz continuous on $[0, 1-\delta]$. $f$ is locally lipschitz on $[0,1)$ so it is continuous on this interval. This allows to use Dini's theorem and concludes the proof.
Remark: In the paragraph 2. we actually proved that the sequence $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous on $[0, 1-\delta]$ intervals, which gives with Arzelà-Ascoli theorem that there exists a uniformly converging subsequence of $(f_n)$ on these intervals, without even knowing whether $(f_n)$ converges pointwise.

+1. Very neat proof!
